# Parsing string to long in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, int

I've written a server in python and the client in C.

The python server send i.e. "1 1000\n" to the C client.

The C function that recieves this string should parse it into two long int's.

```
void receive_job() {
 char tmp_buffer[256];
 long start, stop;
 recv(sock, tmp_buffer, 255, 0);
 /*
 here I wonder how I can parse tmp_buffer to set start and stop values.
 */
}
```

I am not very proficient in C, so I would appreciate a comment on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up `sscanf` manual page - but check the return value!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at strtol() or strtoul(), depending on your concrete data type:

```
char end;
long x = strtol(tmp_buffer,&end,10);
long y = strtol(end+1,NULL,10);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html).

```
char data[] = "1 1000\n";
char *next, *err;
long a = strtol(data, &next, 10);
long b = strtol(next, &err, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to clear the `tmp_buffer` using `memset` before calling `recv` or at least to add a null byte in it. Otherwise it would contain garbage that you might parse if something got transmitted wrongly.

Comment: thanks, I'm currently using sscanf with the expression "%ld %ld\n", so I reckon it shouldn't be necessary to clear the tmp_buffer.